# C# selenium max sessions

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
```

I cannot get it to launch more than 4/5 instances the same time?
how can I increase the max sessions?

```
    MyPool = CustomThreadPool.Instance;
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 15; ctr++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            IWebDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.msn.com");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _driver.Close();
            _driver.Quit();
        }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [testNG/selenium webdriver limited to 5 parallel tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680384/testng-selenium-webdriver-limited-to-5-parallel-tests)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using a Grid.  I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680384/testng-selenium-webdriver-limited-to-5-parallel-tests/24680596#24680596)

Basically you can control the nodes and their sizes by a configuration json file.  It looks like this:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "*chrome",
          "maxInstances": 2,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        }
        ... (any other browser capabilities here)
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 10,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444
  }
}
```

The key there being `maxSession` and `maxInstances`

Comment: I'm not using the grid, I'm using C# Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings

Comment: then that sounds like a restriction of your unit testing framework.  you might have to look more into it

Comment: are you running it in a `Main` method?

Comment: Yes, inside  static void Main(string[] args){}

Comment: then that might be a restriction on your IDE.  Only running 5 main apps at once