# Is it possible to run more than one Selenium test on one node?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium

I have several suites of about 10 Selenium tests written in Java.  I'm using JUnit and some classes that I inherited that extend JUnit classes to run the tests in parallel.

The tests run in parallel just fine if I just use WebDriver without using Grid, but when I try to run the tests in Grid, some of the tests pass, but most fail, usually throwing a NoSuchElementException.

The reason I'm using Grid is so that eventually I can distribute testing, but also so that I can use a background service such as a PHP webpage to execute desktop processes on my Windows server.

I'm using Selenium 2.43.1.
I sometimes execute the tests on my local machine using Windows 7, and other times on my server with Windows Server 2008.

Should I not be using the same node for more than one test?
Should I make virtual machines and execute one test at a time on each?
Any other advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.  I've answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680384/testng-selenium-webdriver-limited-to-5-parallel-tests/24680596#24680596) previously.

Using a configuration json file, you can specify `maxSessions` in tandem with `maxInstances` to control this.

#### nodeConfig.json

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "*chrome",
          "maxInstances": 2,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        }
        ... (any other browser capabilities here)
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 10,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444
  }
}
```

then run your node like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json ...
```